# Continious E2E monitoring with SDK and service discovery support

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, end-to-end, health-monitoring

we have a custom system and I was wondering if there are available analogs we can switch to.

Our system runs various language agnostic test suites against each node of given role. Each test process simply gets target node IP and some values and returns test results in specific format as output.

Questions are:

- What is the proper term for such system?
- Are there any known solutions like this?
- Are there any best practices we can onboard while switching?

[image: Simplified schema]

Wanted features are:

- Web frontend to configure, trigger executions and check results
- Schedulled executions
- Smart alert triggering
  (something like "more than 5 nodes failed the test" or "3 runs in a row had failed tests")
- Language agnostic tests
  (we have SDKs and and helper libraries using different languages, which we are also under test)
- Custom service discovery support
  (basically we want to provide test configuration with role name and scheduller should fetch the list of nodes)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your system made me think of the [Scheduler Agent Supervisor pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/scheduler-agent-supervisor).

I will try to fetch a bit this design pattern known in the distributed systems world with your specific needs for E2E monitoring. These architecture includes 4 main actors, their roles being enunciated in the image below  :

1) **Scheduler** would have the same signification as the scheduler from your schema

2) **The agents** will be the executors from your schema. Note that the diagram below is just a basic example. There can be as many as you want and you decide either if they do or they do not communicate between themselves.

3) **Remote services/ resources** : In your case they will the instances that needed to be tested. They are the resources that your agents will address to.

4) **The Supervisor** : Even though you did not include it in your schema specifically and a supervisor service would be a bit more complex. You can think at your Web UI as a supervisor in your situation. Another idea that I have for your use case would be maybe to split them. To have both a UI to set things up and a Supervisor who monitors the results of the test and which can also communicate with the frontend service. Even though, for the moment it may not be needed, this will let you a lot of room for future improvements and development.

[image]

Even if this does not answer to all of your questions, I hope it will be helpful for you and maybe it may be a start point for more ideas.

Comment: I had hopes that there is some existing tooling for that. I'll guess we either stick to current solution or rewrite it eventually.